# What PHP Blogging Software Should I Choose

Tags: php, comparison, blogs

I am thinking of starting a blog, which I would like integrated into my existing website. I come back empty handed from googling for a comparison of blogging software written in PHP.

My requirements:

- Simple but not rudimentary (not a result of a 15 minute CodeIgniter tutorial)
- Quality source code (I'd like to be able to learn from it and maybe change it)
- Prefer PHP5 over PHP4
- Work with MySQL
- Easy to integrate into an existing website (I don't want it to be a separate application with a different look and feel under a "blog" directory
- Run under safe_mode

Built-in or easy-to-add source code highlighting would be a plus.

Comment: Everyone's recommending WordPress? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481631/why-is-wordpress-considered-to-be-poorly-programmed

Comment: Wouldn't this be better on SuperUser?

Comment: Safe Mode is deprecated in PHP 5.3.0 and is removed in PHP 6.0.0.  <-- From the manual

Comment: Have a look [Exyht](http://exyht.github.io/exyht/).

Answer (score 7):

Many programmers use [Serendipity](http://www.s9y.org/).

Wordpress' code base is really a mess. A bunch of functions operating on global variables.

I don't ask you to simply trust me, or anyone else. Go look yourself at the code!

**And it's written in php4 style, so definitely not what the topic starter asked for.**

Comment: Probably should've given a link: http://www.s9y.org/

Comment: So many up-votes for a system I've never heard of. I'm surprised.

Comment: I wouldn't call it simple and quality code even if it is much better then wordpress. And i dropped it because it's too tight connected with apache and mod rewrite.

Answer (score -4):

why not try with [wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) ? I think really fit in all your points

### Update:

if you still dont like wordpress I can recommend [Mephisto](http://mephistoblog.com/mephisto) which was wrote in ruby. I have tried it but for me was a pain in the ass. Simply wasn't intuitive for me as user.

Comment: I heard that WordPress isn't very well written.

Comment: maybe you can add any other to the comparative: http://bit.ly/64fKGL

Comment: Usage statistics don't address my concern.

Comment: @BigZ the only issue I see for how wordpress was wrote is _scalability_. Unless you plain to have 100k hits on first post I think you can start using it

Comment: The OP wanted something in _PHP_, not ruby.

Answer (score -4):

Wordpress definitely... Great support, many plugins, many themes, etc.

Comment: WP is not PHP5, which is what he said he prefers. Look below for alternatives.

Comment: And WP has sooooo many bugs/hacks.... It's time for another blogging app to become popular!

Answer (score -5):

```
Wordpress, no question.
```

Answer (score -5):

You can always have the best with Wordpress + Host it on your own to utilize all of it's great features.